# Using Terraform to provision ECS, Elastic, SQS, Lambda

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-ecs

I am fairly new to Terraform and had a few questions - 
- I want to provision a ECS cluster with EC2 launch type running containers. I can do this with Terraform.
- I also need a SQS, Lambda talking to the SQS and feeding data to an Elastic cluster who then will interface with another microservice.

My question is, how should I provision this ? 
Is it possible to do all the above in a single ECS cluster using Terraform ? 
Would it be better to have the ECS cluster separate and have the SQS, Lambda, Elastic cluster be independent components ? And have the final microservice run as a separate EC2 container (non-ECS) ?

What is the better way of approaching this infrastructure ?

Comment: You might take a look at this article to see how to use Lambda/SQS/ECS in tandem https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/better-together-amazon-ecs-and-aws-lambda/

Comment: This is a list of questions instead of a single question - to be a good question for SO you need to focus on a specific technical problem or issue that is answerable.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty open-ended question so I can provide some guidance based on experience, but please use your best judgement in applying my experience to your individual use case.

What I found in general is that trying to put unrelated things in the same Terraform module (I suppose that's what you mean when you say "components") is asking for trouble. There's a bunch of things that belong together in an ECS cluster - IAM roles and policies, autoscaling group, cluster itself... see for example [this module](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-ecs). But SQS, Lambda and Elastic don't feel like they're related. I'd put them separately. Same with your non-ECS microservice.

The other thing I'd want to emphasize is that Terraform is not a deployment tool and should not be used to do that. Terraform shines when defining things that change infrequently and independently. The latter is pretty important because Terraform is not transactional and won't roll back anything if things go wrong. If you need more dynamics and a stronger guarantee of integrity in the AWS world, I'd suggest using Terraform to define a [CloudFormation stack](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudformation_stack.html) and running deployments through the latter.